# How to get 1 attribute from XPath in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, xpath

I'm using the GDataXML lib for XPath and this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

His xml looks like this:

```
<Party>
  <Player>
      <Name>Butch</Name>
      <Level>1</Level>
      <Class>Fighter</Class>
      <HP>20</HP>
      <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
  </Player>
  <Player>
      <Name>Shadow</Name>
      <Level>2</Level>
      <Class>Rogue</Class>
      <HP>15</HP>
      <MaxHP>15</MaxHP>
  </Player>
  <Player>
      <Name>Crak</Name>
      <Level>3</Level>
      <Class>Wizard</Class>
      <HP>10</HP>
      <MaxHP>10</MaxHP>
  </Player>
```

But what if there is an attribute in the Name tag, like this:

```
<Player>
    <Name color="red">Butch</Name> // Color attribute 
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Class>Fighter</Class>
    <HP>20</HP>
    <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
</Player>
```

If you look in the tutorial he got this:

```
Party *party = [[[Party alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray *partyMembers = [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"Player"];
for (GDataXMLElement *partyMember in partyMembers) {

// Let's fill these in!
NSString *name;
int level;
RPGClass rpgClass;

// Name
NSArray *names = [partyMember elementsForName:@"Name"];
if (names.count > 0) {
    GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [names objectAtIndex:0];
    name = firstName.stringValue;
} else continue;
...etc
```

He's using a for loop with all the partyMembers in it, and gets each tag, but what if a tag got an attribute like the color one I explained before?

I've tried this:

```
    NSArray *colors = [partyMember nodesForXPath:@"string(/Player/Name/@color)"   error:nil] ;
    if (colors != nil && colors.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstColor = (GDataXMLElement *) [colors objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *color = firstColor.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"%@",color);
    }
```

But this does nothing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
This works:

```
        NSArray *colors = [partyMember nodesForXPath:@"//Player/Name/@color" error:nil] ;
    if (colors != nil && colors.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstColor = (GDataXMLElement *) [colors objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *color = firstColor.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"%@",color);
    }
```

But if you got more color tags like this:

```
    <Player>
    <Name color="red">Butch</Name> // Color attribute 
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Class>Fighter</Class>
    <HP>20</HP>
    <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
</Player>
    <Player>
    <Name color="red">Butch</Name> // Color attribute 
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Class>Fighter</Class>
    <HP>20</HP>
    <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
</Player>
    <Player>
    <Name color="red">Butch</Name> // Color attribute 
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Class>Fighter</Class>
    <HP>20</HP>
    <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
</Player>
```

Then it will print out 3 times red, and I only need it from the first window, then the second iteration in the for loop the second one and so one.

So I was thinking of this:

```
        NSArray *colors = [partyMember nodesForXPath:@"//Player[0]/Name/@color" error:nil] ;
    if (colors != nil && colors.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstColor = (GDataXMLElement *) [colors objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *color = firstColor.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"%@",color);
    }
```

I added the Player[0] and later on I need to change it with the iteration number of the for loop but this does not work.

Comment: I assume that `// Color attribute` comment doesn't actually exist in the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with this code:

```
 NSArray *colors = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Party/Player/Name/@color" error:NULL];
 for (GDataXMLElement *color in colors)
 {
     NSLog(@"Color : %@ ",[color stringValue]);
 }
```

Here:

`doc` is your `GDataXMLDocument`

EDIT:

If you need to set the individual color corresponding to each Name tag, in your loadParty method change:

```
// Name
NSArray *names = [partyMember elementsForName:@"Name"];
if (names.count > 0)
{
    GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [names objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Color : %@",[[firstName attributeForName:@"color"] stringValue]);
    name = firstName.stringValue;
 } else continue;
```

Comment: What is wrong with getting the attribute directly using the code provided by the OP?

Comment: This doesn't work, it says Color : (null) and I need to get rid of that for loop because then he gives me all the attributes at once

Comment: @Shinonuma: please check my edited answer. I tried this and worked for me

Comment: It works, but the problem is that if you watch the tutorial, for 1 "Player" I need to put the color from the Name in a variable, and with your code it prints out everything. If you watch the "loadParty" method:      Player *player = [[[Player alloc] initWithName:name level:level 
            rpgClass:rpgClass] autorelease]; and there I also want to init it with the color from one Player.

Comment: @Shinonuma: again edited according to your need, please check that

Comment: @trojanfoe: his XPath was correct, but he is not reading it from  rootelement.

Comment: Yes, your edit I've tried that too, but it still gives me "red red red red" instead of "red blue green" if your XML has those different colors

Comment: @Shinonuma: I'm using the sample code provided by the tutorial you provided, I just changed the xml and the above code. Nothing more. It's working for me.

Comment: XML I Used: <Party>
    <Player>
        <Name color="red">Butch</Name> // Color attribute
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Class>Fighter</Class>
        <HP>20</HP>
        <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name color="green">Butch</Name> // Color attribute
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Class>Fighter</Class>
        <HP>20</HP>
        <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
    </Player>
    <Player>
        <Name color="blue">Butch</Name> // Color attribute
        <Level>1</Level>
        <Class>Fighter</Class>
        <HP>20</HP>
        <MaxHP>20</MaxHP>
    </Player>
</Party>

Comment: I've took the tutorial code and indeed it works, but in my own project it doesn't.. strange. It gives me 'Color : blue' and then 'Color : (null)" instead of red

Comment: In my project i've removed the "else continue;" because if there is no Name, Class, Level, or whatever it doesn't need to go to the next iteration, but just move on I think the problem has something to do with that

Comment: @Shinonuma: check that there is any Name tag which don't have the color attribute

Comment: There are name tags without that attribute

Comment: @Shinonuma:
1) Add color attribute to all name tag.
2) Check that using : if([[firstName attributeForName:@"color"] stringValue]) and then set it